# OnCreate() of first tab gets called even when second tab is defined as CurrentTab

Tags: tabs, xamarin.android, android-tabhost, oncreate, tabwidget

I have an activity on which I have a `TabHost` and a `TabWidget` like this:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I use the following code to add three tabs and their respective activities to the `TabHost`:

```
private void CreateTabs()
{
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;     // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;            // Reusable Intent for each tab

    String strJson = Intent.GetStringExtra (Constants.JSON_RESPONSE);

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent (this, typeof (FirstActivity));
    if (strJson != null)
    {
        intent.PutExtra (Constants.JSON_RESPONSE, strJson);
    }
    intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("first");
    spec.SetIndicator ("First", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.FirstIcon));
    spec.SetContent (intent);
    TabHost.AddTab (spec);

    // Do the same for second tab
    intent = new Intent (this, typeof (SecondActivity));
    if (strJson != null)
    {
        intent.PutExtra (Constants.JSON_RESPONSE, strJson);
    }
    intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("second");
    spec.SetIndicator ("Second", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.SecondIcon));
    spec.SetContent (intent);
    TabHost.AddTab (spec);

    // Do the same for third tab
    intent = new Intent (this, typeof (ThirdActivity));
    if (strJson != null)
    {
        intent.PutExtra (Constants.JSON_RESPONSE, strJson);
    }
    intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("third");
    spec.SetIndicator ("Third", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.third_icon));
    spec.SetContent (intent);
    TabHost.AddTab (spec);

    //Set the tab you want to show
    TabHost.CurrentTab = 1;
}
```

As you can see that at the last line I am making the second tab to be shown when I open this tabbed activity and that is what it does but actually it first calls the `OnCreate` of `FirstActivity` and then calls `OnCreate` of `SecondActivity` before showing the `SecondActivity`. (The `OnCreate` of `ThirdActivity` is only called when I tap on the third tab to actually see that activity, which is absolutely fine).

I want that the `OnCreate` of `FirstActivity` to be only called when I tap on the first tab because:

1. the app does some work that is not required at that instance and hence using unnecessary resources.
2. More importantly, my `FirstActivity` gets the user's current location and if I get it before the user actually navigates to the required screen then it may not be correct if the user has already changed his location.

Please let me know how to achieve that?

Comment: Would you be better off moving the logic to OnResume() instead?

Comment: That is precisely what I am doing now but I consider it a workaround instead of a solution! Hence looking for a solution.